# Program to list my Facebook contacts that are on LinkedIn but that I am not connected with

Tags: facebook

I am looking for a userscript or program that can list my Facebook contacts that are on LinkedIn but that I am not connected with there. I don't want to use the [import function of LinkedIn](http://www.digitalmarketingdepartment.com/importing-your-facebook-contacts-to-linkedin/) as it [messes up my "People You May Know" list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54924/18147): I just want to have at list of their names or URL to their LinkedIn profiles.